# Script/function forgets the selected ID

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying get multiple data from a database with 2 functions. The first function is working well, but when the second function starts running it seems to be that the second function has forget the ID. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

First of all, this is my PHP script.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cus";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select class='form-control select2' name='cus_id' id='cus_id' onChange='getCus(this.value)' style='width: 100%;'>";
              echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                      echo "<option value='" . $row["cus_id"]. "'>" . $row["cus_id"].  " | " . $row["cus_name"]. "</option>";
     }                   
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

The user can select an `option`. After selecting (onChange event) the function `getCus` gets called. Here is the function `getCus`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function getCus(selectedItem) { 
jQuery.ajax({ 
url: 'get5.php', 
method: 'POST', 
data: {'cus_id' : jQuery('#cus_id').val()},
success: function(response){ 
    jQuery('#cus_id').val(response); 
        jQuery('#cus_name').val(response);
        getCus2(response)

}, 
error: function (request, status, error) { 
alert(request.responseText); 
}, 
}); 
} 
</script>
```

This function runs the script `get5.php` and `get5.php` sends the `cus_name` to the `cus_name` textfield. Up to here everything is working. The function `getCus` starts an new function called `getCus2`. This function looks like the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function getCus2(response) { 

var selectedItem = jQuery('#cus_id option:selected').val();

jQuery.ajax({ 
url: 'get6.php', 
method: 'POST', 
data: {'cus_id' : response},
success: function(response){ 
    jQuery('#cus_id').val(response); 
        jQuery('#cus_cou').val(response);

}, 
error: function (request, status, error) { 
alert(request.responseText); 
}, 
}); 
} 
</script>
```

This script starts `get6.php` that is the same as `get5.php`. The only thing that is different is the response. When the system runs `get6.php` I dont get a response. When I look at the POST in firebug I see that the first function sended the `cus_id` to get5.php. But that there was no `cus_id` send to get6.php. The function(/or php script) forgot for some reason the cus_id.

```
POST get5.php
200 OK
1020ms  
cus_id  23
Source
klant_id=23
```

I cant see whats wrong and what the reason is that my script forgets the selected `cus_id`. Can someone see whats wrong?

**Update 1:**

## cus_id HTML element:

```
 echo "<select class='form-control select2' name='cus_id' id='cus_id' onChange='getCus(this.value)' style='width: 100%;'>";
          echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";
 // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<option value='" . $row["cus_id"]. "'>" . $row["cus_id"].  " | " . $row["cus_name"]. "</option>";
 }                   
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your problem

Comment: I have posted the whole script so you can see what I mean. I dont think the problem is in `get5.php` or `get6.php` which are the little different from each other. I post it because it makes my story complete

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an element to

```
getCus2(selectedItem)
```

But you call it without a parameter.

You could maybe refactor it and instead of the unused selectedItem, send directly the result from getCus, so in getCus2 you don't need to get it from the DOM:

In getCus:

```
getCus2(response)
```

And in getCus2:

```
data: {'cus_id' : selectedItem},
```

Update: try removing the line that alters the value do #cus_id, it seems not needed, and probably that breaks it, 'cause you set some wrong value from the 1st response. Remove this line from **both** functions:

```
jQuery('#cus_id').val(response);
```

It should look like this:

```
function getCus2() { 
    var selectedItem = jQuery('#cus_id option:selected').val();
    console.log("getCus2 before ajax", jQuery('#cus_id').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: 'get6.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {'cus_id' : jQuery('#cus_id').val()},
        success: function(response){ 
            console.log("getCus2 after ajax", jQuery('#cus_id').val());
            jQuery('#cus_cou').val(response);
        }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
            alert(request.responseText); 
        }, 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: You mean something like `getElementById`

Comment: I don't mean, it's in the code you posted, but it's not used in the function ;) but it gave the idea to send the results of the 1st ajax, so it doesn't need the DOM to "pass" it

Comment: After changing `get6.php` is not running anymore

Comment: See POST in my first post. The second POST (POST get6.php) is not posting anymore.

Comment: Can you update the code in the question to what exactly you have now, with my changes? Plus please add console.log("getCus", response);, console.log("getCus2", response); to your Ajax callbacks and also post what the output in the console shows

Comment: In getCus2 either change the function argument back to selectedItem or change selectedItem to response in the data line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104351/discussion-between-john-and-gavriel).

Comment: I added full getCus2 to my answer

Comment: Now get6.php is posting but the post is empty

Comment: add `var_dump($_POST);` as the 1st line in get6.php and tell us what do you see in the response in the browser's console's network tab, and in firebug

Comment: I get `array(0) { }`

Comment: Then you have some other problem in your server. Maybe there's a redirect. You should at least see {'cus_id': SOMETHING} ! Either null or undefined or some real string. Please also post the relevant line from your webserver's access log.

Comment: I use the same code in get5.php or the function for get5.php (getCus2) and the code there is working.

Comment: The function is also working when I delete `getCus` and first call the `getCus2` function. But when i put `getCus` back it stops working. The first function is working well, but the second is not working

Comment: that's odd. What happens when you change the data line to: `data: {'cus_id' : "fake data"},` ?

Comment: Ill get a response when I do that. Ill get the response `array(1) {
  ["cus_id"]=>
  string(9) "fake data"
}`. It posts: `cus_id=fake+data`
"

Comment: And if you have: `function getCus2(response) {console.log("getCus2",response);...`, what does it print?

Comment: When I change "fake data" back to `response` it prints: `array(0) {
}`

Comment: @John, please bare with me!!!!! What is the VALUE of `response`???? Also do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: No, I dont have any javascript errors. When  I change the data back to `data: {'cus_id' : jQuery('#cus_id').val()},` it posts the parameters: `cus_id` the source is: `cus_id=`. The script dont get the selected value. The selected value = 3. This works fine in the first function (getCus) but not in the second function (getCus2)

Comment: See my update, I think removing the lines where you set the value of cus_id might fix it

Comment: No, it is still now working. The script still 'forgets' the selected ID

Comment: can you add `console.log(jQuery('#cus_id').val())` "all over" and see where it is still there and where is the "1st" place where it isn't there?

Comment: Still no response and the same post. Ill get the post `cus_id=` and not `cus_id=3`.

Comment: but what do you see in the console?

Comment: I can see `POST get6.php 200 OK 1027ms`. In the menu Post I can see the parameter: `cus_id` and the source: `cus_id`. The menu response and HTML is empty.

Comment: not in the network tab, in the console. where the output of console.log is displayed

Comment: How can I see the output of console.log. I am using firebug and chrome developer tools and I cant see something called console.log

Comment: Nothing is written here. It is empty

Comment: and you haven't added the console.log^^^^^^^ from 5 hours ago, right? because if you would then at least you should be able to see the log from getCus()...

Comment: Yes, I have console.log in my function. It is empty in the console

Comment: That's impossible. I added the console.log to 2 places in getCas2()! Please add them also in getCas()! You're saying that getCas works, so there has to be some log!

Comment: I tried it again and for some reason I can see the logs not. The console says: `index.php:219 getCus2 before ajax undefined` and `index.php:225 getCus2 after ajax null`

Comment: For getCus I get: `getCus before ajax undefined` and `getCus after ajax 23`

Comment: what is `#cus_id` html element? Can you also include all other parts of the javascript code where `cus_id` is "mentioned"? Whether you read it or set it.

Comment: See `Update 1` in my first post. This is the only place where I use cus_id

Comment: are you changing the <select> with your mouse or keyboard during the ajax? I can't understand why is it changing between them, and even stranger: why it doesn't have a value at the beginning, but does have after the 1st ajax returns

Comment: I am changing the <select> with my mouse. In the select I can select a customer and the function needs to get the name, address, postal code and the country of the customer. The first function gets the name, which is working. The second function needs to get the country but this is not working. I also tried this with other data. The first <select> item is an empty item. This has no value and the user cant select this.